# Return generic of generic

Tags: c#, .net

I want translate this code in Haskell:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

to C#. I've tried:

```
public static T3<T2> Fmap<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2> f, T3<T1> x)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

> Error: The type parameter 'T3' cannot be used with type arguments

I've tried too:

```
public static T3<T2> Fmap<T1, out T2, out T3>(Func<T1, T2> f, T3<T1> x)
```

> Error: Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type
>   parameters can be specified as variant.

Comment: The C# type system does not support higher-kinded types so you can't do this.

Comment: If you have a `public class T3<T>` declared then it should work.

Comment: You should explain what this Haskell snippet does.

Comment: @Dmitry Why class T3<T> and not class T3<T2>?

Comment: It doesn't matter. In a generic class declaration `SomeClass<xxx>` the type argument `xxx` is just a type _name_ and not a reference to a specific type.